# react-native-fbsdk-next expo installation/usage

Tags: react-native, facebook-login, react-native-fbsdk

I'm trying to implement Facebook login in my App (Android and IOS), I'm using Expo.
I tried following the documentation [here](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/#expo-installation) on GitHub but it's not working.

For Android I get:

```
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RCTFBLoginButton" was not found in the UIManager.
```

And for IOS I get:

```
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

My App.json:

```
  "expo": {
    "plugins": [
      [
        "react-native-fbsdk-next",
        {
          "appID": AppID,
          "clientToken": ClientToken,
          "displayName": Display Name,
          "advertiserIDCollectionEnabled": false,
          "autoLogAppEventsEnabled": false,
          "isAutoInitEnabled": true,
          "iosUserTrackingPermission": "This identifier will be used to deliver personalized ads to you."
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
```

and my Facebook login component (Documentation example)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk-next';

export function FaceBook() {

  return (
    <View>
      <LoginButton
        onLoginFinished={
          (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
            } else if (result.isCancelled) {
              console.log("login is cancelled.");
            } else {
              AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                (data) => {
                  console.log(data.accessToken.toString())
                }
              )
            }
          }
        }
        onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")} />
    </View>
  );

};
```

I've been stuck on this for hours researching but I can't find much

Comment: I found this comment but without any solutions just suggesting https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/issues/77

Comment: I saw that thread, but as you said there is no solution.

Comment: @JoelE hi, can you please upload your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in this [doc](https://github.com/thebergamo/react-native-fbsdk-next/#expo-installation)

> This package cannot be used in the "Expo Go" app because it requires custom native code.

Your code is good, but in order to use `native code`, you have to create a [development build](https://docs.expo.dev/development/introduction/) for expo with `react-native-fbsdk-next` ?

You have this [doc](https://docs.expo.dev/development/create-development-builds/) that guide you through necessary steps.

This [doc](https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/apk/) to get the .apk file

That's propably why he cannot find `RCTFBLoginButton`, because it's not yet in the app.

Comment: I decided to go the route of `expo-auth-session/providers/facebook`, since I'm not familiar with android studio and couldn't figure out the dev build

Comment: expo-auth-session/providers/facebook
did it work for I tried it it works only in ios?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by development build?

Comment: here are the docs to create a dev build (so you can use native code)
and a YouTube video if you wan a step by step guide 

Expo:https://docs.expo.dev/development/create-development-builds/
YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=id0Im72UN6w&t=25s